# Append per-host variable to all log messages in Rust using log4rs

Tags: logging, rust

I am new to Rust and using the log4rs library to generate logging messages, and would like to insert a unique-per-host variable in each log message that is written.

I have seen that the [pattern encoder](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.13.0/log4rs/encode/pattern/index.html) provided allows me to insert an arbitrary variable by modifying the MDC, but my application creates several threads, and I am worried about forgetting to pass/initialize the MDC in one of these threads in future development.

Is there a way to insert an arbitrary per-host variable into all logging messages?

I am using a Config Builder rather than a YAML config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that I can generate my encoder string as a variable to be passed in to the PatternEncoder.

For example,

```
    let mut encoder_string = String::from("{d(%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%.3f)} {l}");
    let hostvar = <<function to get per-host variable>>;
    encoder_string.push_str(&hostvar);
    encoder_string.push_str("{P} {T} - {m}{n}");

    // See https://docs.rs/log4rs/*/log4rs/encode/pattern/index.html
    let encoder = Box::new(PatternEncoder::new(
        &encoder_string,
    ));
```